# Multilingual LaTeX document with math/scientific symbols

Tags: multilingual, tex-live

## Hoping for true unicode support as-is in pdfTeX

Trying to get a multilingual LaTeX document that can also display math/science symbols.

Installing `babel`, `babel-vietnamese` and `vntex` (Vietnamese), `cjk` (Chinese) works for Vietnamese and Chinese in a single document. I'm guessing that TeX is at a stage where there cannot be a unified multilingual platform (say, all served by `babel`). So, I think I'm beginning to get this multilingual thing (the T1 and T5 encoding are inside my MWE, as well as `babel` and `cjk`).

The thing I still have problems with is including math/science symbols.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{book}

% Not needed anymore in TeX Live 2018, but babel still needs to learn to chill on this.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Babel gives a warning otherwise.

% Install vntex. t5enc.def is in there.
\usepackage[vietnamese, main=english]{babel}

\usepackage{CJKutf8} % install cjk.

\begin{document}

Testing UTF-8 character here: é

\selectlanguage{vietnamese}

Vietnamese: Tiếng Việt

\selectlanguage{english}

And English again.

\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}

Chinese: 中文

\end{CJK}

Temperature: 26°C

\end{document}
```

## Expected and Actual Result

I would expect pdfTeX Live to "*just display the unicode*" (for degree symbol, 0+00B0), but I actually kinda know why it won't.

## A few additional questions...

Why wasn't CJK included in babel? Because of multi-byte encoding?

I haven't figured out what to do for scientific symbols yet.

Comment: Regarding the first heading: There will never be Unicode support in pdfTeX.  If you need full Unicode, you have to use LuaTeX, which is mostly pdfTeX-compatible.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. Even though I understand your feelings that you might be able to reach a broader audience here on SO, I still reckon that this question really belongs to tex.stackexchange.com. If you don't feel welcome there, this problem should be dealt with on that site.

Comment: @Hagbard Yeah, I feel you. I felt very conflicted posting this here; am a stickler for organization. I'll try to work things out somehow. Sorry for the intrusion.

Comment: @Hagbard OP took a close vote on tex.stackexchange.com as a personal offense.

Comment: @HenriMenke Sorry about that. I'm just very used to my co-workers speed-reading stuff and grasping all details within split-seconds (all native English speakers). Also, I had another question for which my working answer was outright deleted by Barbara. If you're in psychology, I hope you can forgive my mistake in "*transference*".

Comment: @Hagbard Leaving this question here for just 1 day, in case someone comes in and declares unified effort on pdfTeX (and world peace). Beyond that day, I'll close this question in favor of the one that Henri answered in the other forum.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/471080/37907